# If statement for SVG support not adding a class to body

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am seeing if a user has support for SVG, but with no luck. I think perhaps my `if` syntax is wrong?

If the standard W3 statement is found, then add a Class.

```
// Has SVG?
    var divCreate = document.createElement('div');
    divCreate.innerHTML = '<svg/>';
    if (divCreate.firstChild && divCreate.firstChild.namespaceURI == 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg') {
        svgSupported = true;
        $('body').addClass("has-svg");
    }
```

Or do I need the `.innerHTML` to be like:

```
divCreate.innerHTML = '<svg></svg>`
```

I am unsure.

Comment: Works for me. https://jsfiddle.net/e1w7ngom/ Check if you have loaded jquery before this script.

Comment: I have yes. No addClass though?

Comment: `addClass` is jquery function. I'm 100% sure it works provided that you have loaded jquery.

Comment: Also you could use little `<>` button to create a working example demonstrating the issue.